# Convolution, theorem 8.14 Rudin(RCA)

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, convolution

I am studying the proof of the following theorem in Rudin's book (RCA).

[image]

at the beginning of the proff it is necessary to prove that the function

$\hspace{3cm} F(x,y) := f(x-y)g(y)$

is a Borel function on ${\mathbb R}^2$ for to be able to use Fubini's theorem.

my doubt is this:

why F being a Borelian function implies that we can use Fubini's theorem?

by hypothesis of Fubini's theorem, it is only necessary to show that

$\hspace{3cm} F $ is $ (m\times m) $- measurable, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Is that what I should prove? how does this follow from the fact that F is Borelian?

Comment: At first you may forget about the details, assume $f,g$ are piecewise continuous and compactly supported, show the result, and extend to $f,g \in L^1$ by density in $L^1$ of the piecewise continuous compactly supported functions. Intuitively, $|f|$ measurable means you can assign a (possibly infinite) value to $\int_a^b |f| dx$ by approximating $|f|$ by a monotone sequence of simple functions

Comment: how do I use this fact to prove that $F$ is $(m\times m)$-mensurable?

Comment: It is abstract, but I would say $f,g$ measurable means $h(x,y) = (f(x-y),g(y)):\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is measurable, and so is $f(x-y)g(y)$ because $(a,b) \to ab$ is continuous

Comment: I could not see this intermediate step. thank you so much!